# How to install apache atlas on Azure HDInsight?

Tags: azure, azure-hdinsight, apache-atlas

I tried adding apache infra in ambari interface but add service link is not responding.

Comment: would you please add some error message you are getting? That helps people to understand your problem and to find your problem to future users

Comment: i saw somewhere that you can add atlas in ambari interface but the interface should have services like hbase,kafka and ambari infra. I was trying to do the same in ambari interface of hdinsite . to add the service i saw that add service was there in admin section of ambari interface but when i tried to click on add service nothing happened i didn't got any error.so it is not working. so i am asking that is there a way to add these services to the cluster other than the one that i tried?

Answer (score 0):

> Unfortunately, we don’t support Apache Atlas on HDInsight cluster.

**Reference:** [Apache components and versions available for Azure HDInsight](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/hdinsight-component-versioning)

I would suggest you to vote up an idea submitted by another Azure customer.

https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217335-hdinsight/suggestions/35030659-apache-atlas

All of the feedback you share in these forums will be monitored and reviewed by the Microsoft engineering teams responsible for building Azure.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/hadoop/apache-hadoop-on-premises-migration-best-practices-infrastructure                                                                                                    In this link there is atlas can you tell me what does "only hdp" means?

Comment: Only HDP means - Supported on Hortonworks Data Platform (HDP).

Comment: is hdp there is hdinsight?

Comment: Azure HDInsight is a Paas service and which don’t support adding of any services from the Ambari Stack and version settings.

Comment: If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.